# How can I store a webpage title inside a Windows .url file?

Tags: windows, shortcuts, url, links, file-format

This is a question about the `.url` file format:

**How can I store the webpage title inside a Windows `.url` file ?**

I was unable to find an official documentation of the `.url` file format anywhere on the Net. I only found an "[Unofficial Guide to the URL File Format](https://www.lyberty.com/encyc/articles/tech/dot_url_format_-_an_unofficial_guide.html)" according to which the `.url` file structure is as follows in this sample file:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.someaddress.com/
WorkingDirectory=C:\WINDOWS\
ShowCommand=7
IconIndex=1
IconFile=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM\url.dll
Modified=20F06BA06D07BD014D
HotKey=1601
```

I am looking for something like

```
TITLE=This is the webpage title!
```

or

```
NAME=This is the webpage title!
```

Is there any official `.ini` value to store the webpage title?
Honestly, I'd find it pretty weird if this was missing.

[In Linux you can do exactly that](https://askubuntu.com/a/359495) with `name=...` in `.desktop` files (which are the equivalent of `.url` files in Windows).

With regards to Windows `.url` files, [this webpage](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/internet-shortcut-files.html) claims (rightly or wrongly):

> You can optionally include the Title= and Desc= properties

But I could not find any authoritative resource confirming (or contradicting) this claim.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://archive.is/20230524231515/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/internet-shortcuts#selection-2501.0-2509.29) ([mirror](https://archive.is/DVgVE#selection-23147.0-23147.11)) says there is a property `ID PID_IS_NAME` which is the *"Name of the Internet shortcut"*. Does this mean, we can use `NAME` as follows?

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.someaddress.com
NAME=This is the webpage title!
```

In case there really isn't an officially designated way to do so, will I possibly break any functionality, if I just add `title=...` for myself (as a personal hack)? Even if Windows will not detect this information and cannot use it, at least I would have this information stored for my personal reference.

Comment: Even if that is possible, where exactly do you want to see that title? When opening the shortcut in a browser, it will typically take the title from the actual html file. I can see some value when importing an url file as a bookmark, but I'm not sure that's what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.URL` file format is not officially documented. Only the `URL` value
in the `InternetShortcut` section is required, everything else is optional.

A list of the possible values is given in the NSIS article
[Creating internet shortcuts](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/CreateInternetShortcut_macro_&_function):

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=
HotKey=
IconFile=
IconIndex=
ShowCommand=
Modified=
Roamed=
IDList=
Author=
WhatsNew=
Comment=
Desc=
```

There is no information about what will happen if a value-name
is used that is not known to exist, such as `TITLE`.
It might be better to avoid using invented values, as even
if this will work in some Windows versions, there is no guarantee
that it will continue on working.

But you could use just as well the `Comment` value.

Comment: good answer. I interpret your answer as saying a specific value for the webpage title does not exist. If you can edit your answer so as to confirm this (because this was essentially my main question), I will mark your answer as *"accepted answer"*. It would be great if you could somehow document that there is no such value, although I admit that by definition it is difficult to prove that something does *not* exist (*negativa non sunt probanda*).

Comment: Is that clearer ?

Comment: It already WAS clear and perfectly understandable before. I was just looking for an authoritative answer confirming that there is no designated value for the webpage title if you could add such a statement (if possible using a documentable reference, but as I said, I admit it will be hard to find a reference explaining that something does *not* exist ...)

Comment: The NSIS article was the best source I found, Microsoft kept it undocumented on purpose, perhaps there were future plans that were never implemented. I counsel using a known value only for caution, not from any knowledge, because one never knows.

Comment: It's just weird that there is a field for WhatsNew but none for the webpage title? Is it really possible that something so obvious is missing? I just came across another website (added to my question above) that claims `title=` exists. I cannot find any official resource confirming or contradicting this claim.

Comment: It might be that `title=` "works" because unknown entries are ignored ...